# Android App Text Ghosting

Tags: android, xml, display

Source Code: https (colon Slash Slash) github (dot) com/rileyclauss/PHSMobile

Android Studio text ghosts on screen when building.

When building my application, [SEE EDIT 3] when I scroll, the text will remain fully translucent, making it impossible to read text. [Certain aspects will also be visual gibberish, images "tile-ing," static, etc.] This occurs on every activity, no matter the contents of the code (even with it empty.)

This example shows the issue:
[normal text](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1839F.png) as opposed to what it looks like now, [torn text](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lux7l.png)

Is there any solution for this? The only code executed is to set the layout like this, so it isn't a memory issue. Any help at all would be greatly appreciated.

EDIT1: Here is the Java code I'm using

```
package com.phsapp.phsapp;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;

public class aboutActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) { //Yeah, this is it
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_about);

    }
}
```

and the XML is here:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/activity_about"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="com.phsapp.phsapp.aboutActivity">

<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView56">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:weightSum="1">

        <Space
            android:layout_width="1dp"
            android:layout_height="5dp"/>

        <TextView
            android:text="@string/introtext"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/textView57" />
        <Space
            android:layout_width="1dp"
            android:layout_height="5dp"/>

        <TextView
            android:text="@string/introtext2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/textView58" />

        <Space
            android:layout_width="1dp"
            android:layout_height="5dp"/>

        <TextView
            android:text="@string/introstats"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/textView59" />
        <Space
            android:layout_width="1dp"
            android:layout_height="5dp"/>
        <TextView
            android:text="@string/introtext3"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/textView60" />
        <Space
            android:layout_width="1dp"
            android:layout_height="5dp"/>

        <TextView
            android:text="@string/points_of_pride"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/textView61"
            android:textStyle="normal|bold"
            android:textSize="16sp" />

        <Space
            android:layout_width="1dp"
            android:layout_height="5dp"/>

        <TextView
            android:text="@string/POP1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/textView62" />

        <Space
            android:layout_width="1dp"
            android:layout_height="5dp"/>

        <TextView
            android:text="@string/POP2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/textView63" />

        <Space
            android:layout_width="1dp"
            android:layout_height="5dp"/>

        <TextView
            android:text="@string/POP3"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/textView64" />

        <Space
            android:layout_width="1dp"
            android:layout_height="5dp"/>

        <TextView
            android:text="@string/POP4"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/textView65" />

        <Space
            android:layout_width="1dp"
            android:layout_height="5dp"/>

        <TextView
            android:text="@string/POP5"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/textView66" />
        <Space
            android:layout_width="1dp"
            android:layout_height="5dp"/>
        <TextView
            android:text="@string/POP6"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/textView67" />
        <Space
            android:layout_width="1dp"
            android:layout_height="5dp"/>
        <TextView
            android:text="@string/quick_facts"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/textView68"
            android:textStyle="normal|bold"
            android:textSize="16sp" />
        <Space
            android:layout_width="1dp"
            android:layout_height="5dp"/>
        <TextView
            android:text="@string/enrollmentfact"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/textView69" />
        <Space
            android:layout_width="1dp"
            android:layout_height="5dp"/>
        <TextView
            android:text="@string/tasfact"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/textView70" />
        <Space
            android:layout_width="1dp"
            android:layout_height="5dp"/>
        <TextView
            android:text="@string/schedule"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/textView71" />
        <Space
            android:layout_width="1dp"
            android:layout_height="5dp"/>
        <TextView
            android:text="@string/schoolcolors"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/textView72" />
        <Space
            android:layout_width="1dp"
            android:layout_height="5dp"/>
        <TextView
            android:text="@string/mascot"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/textView73" />
        <Space
            android:layout_width="1dp"
            android:layout_height="5dp"/>
        <TextView
            android:text="@string/constructed_1958"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/textView74" />
        <Space
            android:layout_width="1dp"
            android:layout_height="5dp"/>
        <TextView
            android:text="@string/extensively_renovated_1996"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/textView75" />
        <Space
            android:layout_width="1dp"
            android:layout_height="5dp"/>
        <TextView
            android:text="@string/buildingsize"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/textView76" />
        <Space
            android:layout_width="1dp"
            android:layout_height="5dp"/>
        <TextView
            android:text="@string/class_structure"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/textView77" />
        <Space
            android:layout_width="1dp"
            android:layout_height="5dp"/>
        <TextView
            android:text="@string/schoolschedule"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/textView78" />
        <Space
            android:layout_width="1dp"
            android:layout_height="20dp"/>

        <Button
            android:text="Credits"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/button3"
            android:layout_weight="0.05" />
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/abouthead"
    android:id="@+id/imageView3"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:cropToPadding="true"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
    android:contentDescription="@string/abouttext" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/textView56"
    android:text="@string/comittedexcelence"
    android:textSize="18sp"
    android:textStyle="normal|bold"
    android:textAlignment="center"
    android:layout_below="@+id/imageView3"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />
```

Every string resource is extracted.

Android Studio 2.3

Build #AI-162.3764568, built on February 24, 2017

JRE: 1.8.0_112-release-b06 amd64

JVM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o

In getting this code, I discovered that it is also tearing in Android Studio itself. Is this possibly an issue with my computer?

OS: Windows 10, build 14393

CPU: Intel Xeon 4-Core 2.67GHz

Memory: 16GB

EDIT 3:
After a bit more testing, I was able to determine that this only occurs on devices that do not use their GPU to render the screen. Using a Nexus 5X (Android 7.1.2), for example, without forcing the GPU to be used, the GPU would not be used and the CPU would try to render everything, failing and causing what is seen above. Testing on a Samsung Galaxy S7 (Android 7.0) naturally uses GPU, and everything looks as it should. On a Moto E 2nd Gen (Android 7.1.2), Force GPU Rendering needs to be enabled for it to work properly.
I have put (android:hardwareAccelerated="true") into my Android Manifest but to no avail, the problem persists. This issue also occurs on the IDE itself. When in "Design" mode on an XML file, scrolling causes the same issue. Text will draw but not erase. This happens on both a low-tier and mid-tier computer. 
Any solution or workaround is more than welcomed.

Comment: are you doing anything fancy in your code? like overriding **onDraw** :)

Comment: @waqaslam No, I'm doing nothing in my code as you can see above.

Comment: use line spacing

Comment: are you using hardware accelerated emulator? if not then try enabling that or use a real device

Comment: @waqaslam It happens on both an emulator and a real android device.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SOLUTION:
If you visit the GitHub link provided, and visit any older version, you can see I had implemented a custom theme that had a "NoActionBar" parent. When I changed the theme to have an action bar, the problem stopped on all devices, including in the IDE itself.